# Django download file set correct name

Tags: django

Right now I use the following function for downloading files:

```
def download_xlsx(request):
    user = request.user
    file_name = request.GET['file_name']
    file_path='main_app/static/xlsx/' + str(user.id) + '/' + file_name
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename=%s" % file_name
            return response
```

Using the following url http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_xlsx?file_name=test.xlsx

I downloaded file named 'download_xlsx'

I tried to write something like this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename='+ file_name
```

But didn't help.
How do I rename my file to `file_name` var ?
UPD: it seems to be the problem with non-english file_names. But still don't know how do deal with it

Comment: What is the output if you hard-code the `file_name` variable?

Comment: if I hardcode, output is correct

Answer (score 0):

Works like this(the problem was in encoding)

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename=%s" % file_name.encode('utf-8')
```